# What is the most efficient way to match the vector with glosary?

Tags: r

I have vector called "valuesx" and a glosary which consists of vector "labelsx" and a names of vector called "namesx". I want to create a new vector which values corresponds to the namesx on valuesx.

I can do this like this:

```
  #data
    labelsx <- 1:5
    namesx <- c("label1","label2","label3","label4","label5")
    names(labelsx) <- namesx
    valuesx <- sample(namesx,20,replace=T)

    #now, how to match them in better way than this:
    dt <- data.frame(labelsx, n = names(labelsx))
    dt2 <- data.frame(valuesx)
    merge(dt, dt2, by.x = "n", by.y = "valuesx")
```

is there better way? without data frames?

Comment: ya're right, thx.

Comment: The answer might be in your title... `match(valuesx, namesx)`.

Comment: `sort(match(valuesx, namesx))` corresponds with the second column of the merged data.frame, and `namesx[sort(match(valuesx, namesx))]` corresponds to the first column.

Comment: thx thx thx thx